# Installing YARA on OS X 10.11?

Tags: osx-elcapitan, yara

I have been trying to figure out how to install YARA on El Capitan, but even if I try disabling SIP, it just doesn't work. Does anyone know what's necessary to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that something was screwed up with both my Mac systems. Installing YARA is as simple as installing Homebrew, then calling "brew install yara". This wasn't working because somehow my Homebrew installation had gotten damaged.